# How can i insert 2 for loops into print function in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

im having problam to insert 2 for loops into my print function , 
im trying to print the following :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20],
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30], 
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40], 
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50], 
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60],
[0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70],
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80],
[0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90],
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]
```

in 1 print line!

my try for this:
`print ( for y in range(11)  [x*y for x in range(11)] )`

please if someone can guide me it will help me alot

Comment: the indented lists are my bad ..its not what i meant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print([[x * y for x in range(11)] for y in range(11)])
```